# Trouble setting up mail server(postfix, dovecot) on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: postfix, dovecot

i have a server with ip adrress 192.168.11.xx and i have DNS server with ip address from isp 203.174.12.xx

and i build a mail server with postfix and dovecote, with ip address 192.168.11.xx same with ip my server,
with domain domain.xx.xx , mail server mail.domain.xx.xx but i just can send mail from localhost,

```
:~# telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ns1.domain.xx.xx ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
mail from:root
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:imam
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
this data
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E4832181A08
```

if i use telnet with 192.168.11.xx

```
:~# telnet 192.168.11.xx 25
Trying 192.168.11.53...
Connected to 192.168.11.xx.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ns1.ns1.domain.xx.xx ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
mail from:root
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:imam
451 4.3.0 <imam>: Temporary lookup failure
if i use telnet with mail.domain.xx.xx

:~# telnet mmail.domain.xx.xx 25
Trying 192.168.11.xx...
Connected to mail.domain.xx.xx.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ns1.titan.biz.id ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
mail from:root
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:imam
451 4.3.0 <imam>: Temporary lookup failure
```

and for imap and pop3 i can't telnet it

```
:~# telnet localhost 143
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

:~# telnet localhost 110
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

please help me :)

Comment: how to fix it ?

Comment: I would recommend to provide the requested information to the original question, instead of just posting the question again. This is heavily discouraged on Stack Exchange, and expect your replicated question to be closed/deleted therefor.